# Возможно ли записать функцию __binary__ в одно строку если да то как?

Tags: python, python-3.x

должен возвращать список из 0 и 1. 1 если елемент списка (a) входит в список [range(10)] , в ином случае 0. К примеру a = [1,7,8,9] **binary**(a) = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]

```py
def __binary__(a):
    u = []
    for i in range(10):
        if i in a:
            u.append(1)
        else:
            u.append(0)
    return u


one = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(__binary__(one))
```

Comment: Посмотрите на генераторы списков это позволит укоротить код... Главное чтобы это некому потом не нужно было читать (и Вам тоже спустя пару па месяцев...)

Comment: А что должна возвращать _ _ binary _ _?

Comment: TigerTV.ru , должен возвращать список из 0 и 1. 1 если елемент списка (a) входит в список [range(10)] , в ином случае 0. К примеру a = [1,7,8,9] __binary__(a) = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]

Comment: `list(map(one.count, range(10)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def __binary__(a):
    return [i in a for i in range(10)]
```